# Is it possible to know the questions and answers by a no longer user?

Tags: support, search, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

When a user decides to delete their own account or when for some reason the account is deleted, then you can't see any information about the user, you can't click on the id "name" of the user.

Is it possible to know what were all of his/her questions and answers?

**edit**

Notice that this question is different from this [other question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/is-it-possible-to-know-the-name-of-a-user-with-account-deleted?noredirect=1&lq=1)

An example to explain this was provided by Martin Sleziak (in the comments section)

> > These are two different questions. For example, if I delete my account, my posts will show user8297 as the poster. This question is asking whether from knowing the deleted users' id (8297 in this example), it is possible to find all posts by that user. The question which was suggested as a duplicate is asking whether from id we can find out the username which the user was using before the deletion (in this example Martin Sleziak).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to know the name of a user with account deleted?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/is-it-possible-to-know-the-name-of-a-user-with-account-deleted)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee no it's not the same

Comment: I agree with Bellatrix that these are two different questions. For example, if I delete my account, my posts will show user8297 as the poster. This question is asking whether from knowing the deleted users' id (8297 in this example), it is possible to find all posts by that user. The question which was suggested as a duplicate is asking whether from id we can find out the username which the user was using before the deletion (in this example Martin Sleziak).

Comment: @MartinSleziak exactly. And you know, I don't why my question currently has 3 votes to close

Comment: Well, at least some users voted to leave open [in the review](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/4653). If the question gets closed, we can simply try to reopen it again.

Comment: if you look up @RoddyMacPhee you'll find parts of my previous account so it sort of is if you've got a previous username from id, you can search for every question they got a personal comment on.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee huh? "if you look up '@RoddyMacPhee' you'll find parts of my previous account so it sort of is if you've got a previous username from id"

Comment: very simply use the method to find their previous username, then search @< username >  that will bring up any comments to them previously as part of the results. unless another user takes that name since then or prior you can guarantee it'll be towards them.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee there could be a problem then because what if the name is `John Doe`

Comment: you'll find 5 results on main if you put that together... you can literally type the number into search and potentially get matches drop the user part.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee then just `john`

Comment: @JohnDoe works if they have a space.

Comment: @MartinSleziak can you believe they marked as duplicated my question?

Comment: @MartinSleziak i'm going to edit my question and add your comment to explain how they are different.

Comment: Similar question on MathOverflow Meta: [Is there a way to check all questions/answers posted from a deleted account](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3748).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find posts by a deleted user if you have the userid you can use [Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). See also: [Is there a way to check all questions/answers posted from a deleted account](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3748) (MathOverflow Meta) and Shadow Wizard's answer to [Why not keep anonymous profiles accessible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270541#270544) (Meta Stack Exchange).

Some examples of SEDE queries:

- [Get posts list of a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=98602)
- [Questions of a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942474/questions-of-a-deleted-user?userid=98602)
- [Answers of a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942475/answers-of-a-deleted-user?userid=98602)
- [Questions of a deleted user with a given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942476/questions-of-a-deleted-user-with-a-given-tag?userid=98602&tagname=algebraic-topology)
- [Answers of a deleted user in a given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1191925/answer-of-a-deleted-user-in-a-given-tag?userid=98602&tagname=algebraic-topology)
- [Comments by a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1189200/comments-by-a-deleted-user?userid=98602)

Comment: .Thanks Martin!

Comment: Two more examples of similar queries: [answer in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1191925/answer-of-a-deleted-user-in-a-given-tag?userid=98602&tagname=algebraic-topology) and [comments by a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1189200/comments-by-a-deleted-user?userid=98602).