# Why when a user account is suspended, is suspended in both math.meta.stack and math.stack?

Tags: discussion, meta, account-suspension

Why when a user account is suspended, is suspended in both math.meta.stack and math.stack?

That seems like double punishment for only one fault.

If you are a good contributor math.stack and for some reason you break the rules on meta, then you should be suspended only on meta, me thinks; and vice versa. Or why double suspension?

Both are clearly related but they are totally different.

Comment: Are there rules that are different on the main site to the meta site?  If not, aren't you breaking the rules on both when you break them on one?

Comment: They can still use meta, i.e. to complain if they feel that their suspension was unwarranted.

Comment: FWIW I can only think of one instance where a user has been suspended *exclusively* for their behavior on meta. It's almost always either main or both.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I didn´t know.. I checked the list of suspended users and could see that for some of them this applied.

Comment: There's a list of suspended users???

Comment: @postmortes one could be rude here but _always_ keep the composure when one is on main, so one should not be suspended on both

Comment: @lsa may I know how to find the list?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes. I knew because of the answer Martin gave here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30273/is-it-possible-to-know-the-questions-and-answers-by-a-no-longer-user click on any link Martin provided and redirects you to a page where there are a lot of querys and then you need to search for something like 'suspended users' and there will show many links about it, click one of them and then click on the search button, IIRC and you're done.

Comment: I suppose @Isa is talking about various [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) queries trying to [find suspended users](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/queries?q=suspended) such as [Finding possible suspended users](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/901680/finding-possible-suspended-users), [Suspended users](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/632466/suspended-users) or [Potentially suspended users](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942418/potentially-suspended-users).

Comment: @Isa that doesn't answer my question I'm afraid: I asked you if there were rules different from one site to another.  It's *always* easy to say that if a rule applies to all sites in a network then breaking it anywhere results in punishment everywhere -- when you start making exceptions you then have to start arbitrating.

Comment: Related posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Should suspensions on parent sites follow through to meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62757) and [Please give suspended users an option to explain their side of the story on the meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326416).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks Martin for the new links

Comment: @postmortes I think the answer is no. But just because the rules are the same doesn't mean you have to be suspended on both. Say it's forbidden to eat during any class and then you star to eat in algebra class then your prof. tells you to leave and not to come back in the next 3 days, clearly this does not imply that you have forbidden access to the rest of the classes, say geometry, topology,etc. even when the rule is the same on all of them

Comment: @Isa a more accurate analogy would be that you start to eat in class and get suspended from *the school* for three days; so you would be.  You've broken a *school* rule, not a *class* rule.

Comment: @postmortes Yes :D that's more accurate. So the school suspends you for three days. Because  you've broken a school rule. Does it makes sense to you? You are going to miss important classes (geometry and topology) just because one thing you were not supposed to do on algebra class..You deserve the 3 days suspension in algebra class **only**

Comment: @Isa: suspending you from algebra class sends the message that you shouldn't break rules in algebra, but the desired message is that you don't break rules in school.  The transgression is against the *school* rule, so it's not inappropriate for the punishment to be at a *school* level.  Would you also argue that since gum is smaller and less messy than an apple that you should be suspended for less time for chewing gum than for eating an apple?  What about a three-course meal?

Comment: @postmortes well I think we will never agree

Answer (score 4):

The accounts meta and main are in a way two sides of the same coin, one cannot have one without the other. They are also 'linked' in other aspects, e.g., display name.

Is this good? Well, it certainly could be different. It was different in the old days on SO and MO. The meta was separate, and the main Meta exists as a standalone site to this day.

Two arguable reasons for always suspending in parallel.

- Users suspended on main might turn to meta to argue their case right away. This might seem desirable. But in practice it often ends very badly.
- Users might not care enough about meta per se and the risk of getting suspended only on meta might not be a deterrent.

But certainly one can argue in the other direction too. Either way, currently it's not possible to suspend separately and I doubt anyone will care enough to change it.

Note though that a suspension on one SE site does not carry over to other SE sites. Only in very rare cases is an account suspended network-wide, that is, everywhere except on the main Meta.

Comment: I don't think that's fair. The second bullet, what if is the opposite case. Say for instance you get suspended on main for breaking the rules (1 month) and since currently it's not possible to suspend separately you won't be on meta neither; that wouldn't be fair at all since you are a featured contributor on meta.

Comment: What is a "featured contributor of meta" and how is this relevant?

Comment: A good contributor. Why would we want a good contributor (helps others) on meta to be suspended?

Comment: What if some is suspended because they got upset because a questions of them was closed? Why would we not continue to allow to give answers where this problem did not and cannot occur? Somewhere one draws the line. And it's drawn where it is drawn. As I said there is no super-compelling reason for thing being as they are, yet neither is there one for changing it.

Comment: I don't understand your questions, specially the 2nd, I don't know what you mean. \\ 'yet neither is there one for changing it.' 

Comment: Sorry the phrase got a bit garbled. If somebody gets suspended for complaining to aggressively about the closure of one of their questions, why do we suspended them from answering questions, we could just suspended them from asking, right?

Comment: no. They should get suspended from both: asking and answering. The difference remains on the sites, main and meta. Anyway since you, a moderator, said that you doubt anyone will care enough to change it, then I think there is no point on continuing talking about it.