# Is it possible to search past answers of a deleted account?

Tags: support, search, deleted-accounts

I've recently come across a [couple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po#:%7E:text=user137731) of [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129) that I've found really useful. Usually I'd like to view other answers by the same user. However this account has been deleted, which makes it difficult.

Is it possible to view the answers of a deleted account in a similar way to active user accounts?

I've tried searching the mathematics site for the username but nothing appears. Using a search engine is also not much use as the majority of results link to comments made by the user.

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to know the questions and answers by a no longer user?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30273) (on this meta). In my answer there I link to related posts on some other metas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/queries). In particular using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1265694/posts-by-a-deleted-user) query you need to enter the deleted user's displayname and the non-deleted posts will be shown ordered by their Score.

For example [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1265697/posts-by-a-deleted-user?Name=user137731) will be the result for the user you mentioned in the question.